# Add new address in the end of array JSON formatted javascript variables

Tags: javascript, json

I have this variable and I want to add other dynamically because I read the `latlng`, `name`, etc. from an XML file.

```
var stationMapList = [
    {"latlng":[41.38506,2.17340],name:"Barcelona", pin:'img/pin_2.png', id:'address0', tab:'tab1-button'},
    {"latlng":[41.11902,1.24521],name:"Tarragona", pin:'img/pin.png', id:'address1', tab:'tab1-button'},
]
```

I want to add these to `stationMapList`, how can I do it?

```
{"latlng":[40.41678,-3.70379],name:"Madrid", pin:'img/pin_2.png', id:'address2' ,tab:'tab1-button'},
{"latlng":[37.99233,-1.13046],name:"Murcia", pin:'img/pin.png', id:'address3' ,tab:'tab1-button'},
{"latlng":[39.46991,-0.37629],name:"Valencia", pin:'img/pin.png', id:'address4' ,tab:'tab1-button'}
```

Comment: Show more useful information, it's still insufficient to figure out.

Comment: What are the backend technologies you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information provided, this is the possible solution I came up with

```
var stationMapList = [
    {"latlng":[41.38506,2.17340],name:"Barcelona", pin:'img/pin_2.png', id:'address0', tab:'tab1-button'},
    {"latlng":[41.11902,1.24521],name:"Tarragona", pin:'img/pin.png', id:'address1', tab:'tab1-button'},
    {"latlng":[40.41678,-3.70379],name:"Madrid", pin:'img/pin_2.png', id:'address2' ,tab:'tab1-button'},
    {"latlng":[37.99233,-1.13046],name:"Murcia", pin:'img/pin.png', id:'address3' ,tab:'tab1-button'},
    {"latlng":[39.46991,-0.37629],name:"Valencia", pin:'img/pin.png', id:'address4' ,tab:'tab1-button'}
]
```